# JSP information page creation

Tags: jsp, tomcat

To get all information about php installation and configuration we will create a sample php page with following code.

```
<? phpinfo() ?>
```

So can somebody let me know how we can create such sample page for JSP?

Comment: There is no equivalent. What would you like to know? The main point of phpinfo is to know which php libraries are available, but Java doesn't really need that, since you typically bundle all the libraries yoy need in the application itself.

Comment: Thank you. Okay, could you let me know how to check the current heap memory set for tomcat

Comment: You can use the pre-installed "Manager" app. After adding username and password to the tomcat-users.xml file, click on the "Server Status" button on Tomcat's home page.

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check Java version</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Java runtime version: <%=System.getProperty("java.version") %></h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then run Tomcat, result:

> Java runtime version: 1.8.0_102

Comment: Thanks, I know how to check Java version. I need to know how to check current heap memory set for tomcat.